# Spinner item select and change fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I select the `spinner` `fragment` can change but previous `fragment` stay in `activity`. How to make disappear the `previous` `fragment`?
My code:

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelectionAndItemSelectHandling() {
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(UsersActivity.this, String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("Корзина")) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ShoppingBasket sb = (ShoppingBasket)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("sb");
                if(sb == null){
                    sb = new ShoppingBasket();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, sb, "sb");
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                }
                else {
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(sb);
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
                }

                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

            if(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("Пополнить баланс")) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                AddBalance ab = null;
                if(ab == null){
                    ab = new AddBalance();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container2, ab, "ab");
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                }
                else {
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(ab);
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
                }

                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: check once whether R.id.fragment_container is the frame you want to replace, or may be visibility issue so use some background color to next fragment.

Comment: don't add fragment to backstack

Comment: for every fragment i create new container and when selected item1 i add fragment1 , when item 2 - fragment2 , but fragment1 not deleted from activity

Comment: where you are replacing the fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, sb);
```

with

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace fragments like this

```
fm.beginTransaction()
        .replace(fragmentB, R.id.container)
.addToBackstack(null)
.commit();
```

Comment: second fragment replace:

Comment: if(ab == null){
                        ab = new AddBalance();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, ab)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    }
                    else {
                        fragmentTransaction.remove(ab);
                        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
                    }

Comment: first fragment ShoppingBasket sb = null;
                    if(sb == null){
                        sb = new ShoppingBasket();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, sb, "sb");
                        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    }
                    else {
                        fragmentTransaction.remove(sb);
                        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
                    }

                    fragmentTransaction.commit();